# How to enable incognito mode in PyQtWebEngine?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I am making a web browser using PyQtWebEngine but how will I give the feature of incognito mode in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the example that I already pointed out in a previous post: [WebEngine Widgets Simple Browser Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html). In the [Implementing Private Browsing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html#implementing-private-browsing) section they point out that it is enough to provide a [`QWebEngineProfile()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html) different from [`QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#defaultProfile) since the latter is shared by all pages by default, which is what is not searched for in a private browsing.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class WebView(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, off_the_record=False, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        profile = (
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile()
            if off_the_record
            else QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile()
        )
        page = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage(profile)
        self.setPage(page)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = WebView(off_the_record=True)

    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.qt.io"))
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```